# MySQL Workbench se cierra repentinamente al ejecutar un comando

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, macos

tengo un problema con MySQL Workbench. Uso una MacBook Pro Early 2015, Intel Core i5 de 2,7 GHz, ejecuto macOS Monterey y MySql 8.0.32 Community de 64 bits; funciona bien para crear, eliminar e insertar datos en una base de datos; el problema es que cuando uso el comando SELECT * FROM, MySQL Workbench se cierra inesperadamente; La tabla que estoy creando inserté solo 1 dato, por lo que no puede ser un uso excesivo de memoria. ¿Qué recomiendan hacer?

[image: Mi codigo]

Después de ejecutar eso, se cierra la app.

Comment: Hola Angelo, bienvenido,  esto es SOes, el idioma soportado es el español, te sugiero que traduzcas tu pregunta o la traslades a SO, así evitarás recibir votos negativos,  para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código y los mensajes de error (si es que los recibes) en formato texto, y que nos expliques en que falla, mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada. aprovecha y haz el recorrido de Bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!

Comment: ¿Una MacBook Pro del futuro?!

Comment: @Sal , es verdad, quería escribir 2015 jeje

Comment: @MarcePuente muchas gracias; no sabía estar en SOes; respecto a mensaje de error, no lo obtengo, solo dígito el SELECT * FROM <<nombre_tabla>> y cierra el Workbench repentinamente.

Comment: No tienes nada que agradecer, es un placer, lo que si tienes que hacer, es traducir la pregunta, la van a cerrar, por otro lado, es imposible brindarte ayuda sin ver tu código, puedes editar la pregunta, traducirla y agregar tu código en formato texto.

Comment: @MarcePuente listo traducida; como verás el codigo es bastante sencillo; solo USE db, y SELECT * FROM; después de eso, se cierra la app.

Comment: @MarcePuente que codigo? no querras decir mejor ver los logs de aplicacion?

Comment: @gbianchi-enhuelga, y van dos!

Comment: @MarcePuente ya lo resolvi, de tanto buscar como ver los logs (en Mac no los encuentro :-( ) encontre que la falla era común en la versión que usaba 8.0.32, así que me bajé la 8.0.31 y ahora funciona. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Grande maestro, un ídolo total!.